# reshaping , fitting multicolumn table

Tags: tables, tabularx

Hello I have a code below and I would like to fit it to page and center the values base on the row with of the search word. many thanks in advance.[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary,array,tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcolumntype{z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}
        {%l
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm} 
            %>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm} 
            c
            c
            %>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
            c
            c
            c
            c
            c}
        \toprule  
        Search Words & Period & Search Technique & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Initial Search Results} & Final Sample &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Analysis Perform}\tabularnewline
        \cline{4-5} \cline{5-5} 
        &  &  & No. of articles & Total local citations &  &  & \tabularnewline
        (("determinants" or "discrimination") and ("finance" or "credit" or  "capital" or "financial services") and ("access")) & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5\tabularnewline
        & &\tabularnewline
        ("financial inclusion") & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5\tabularnewline
        \bottomrule%
    \end{tabularx}%
    \caption{caption.}
    \label{tab:final.sample.biblio} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A `tabularx` environment without any `X` type column doesn't make sense. To start, you could try to replace the `p` type column you currently use for the first column with an `X` type column. To save some space, allow line breaks in the column headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my previous comment, a `tabularx` environment without any `X` type column doesn't make sense. The first step is replacin the `p` type column you currently use for the first column with an `X` type column. Since this column now gets too narrow, we could allow line breaks inside of the column headers. To do so, I used the `\thead` command from the `makecell` package. In order to avoid large spaces inside of the first column, I added `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}` to switch from justified to ragged right alignment. I also replaced the `\cline` commands with `\cmidrule` from the `booktabs` package, that you already used. I also slightly reduced the value of `\tabcolsep` and increased the font size from `\footnotesize` to `\small`. In order to vertically center the contents of each cell with respect to the contents in the first column, I added  `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`. Lastly, I couldn't understand the reason for `\cline{4-5} \cline{5-5}` and guessed that there were some column headers missing in the last two columns, so I added them.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \small
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\theadalign}{tc}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \caption{caption.}
    \label{tab:final.sample.biblio} 
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}
        {@{}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
            c
            c 
            c
            c
            c
            c
            c @{}}
        \toprule  
        \thead[l]{Search Words} & \thead{Period} & \smash{\thead{Search\\ Technique}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Initial Search Results}} &  \smash{\thead[t]{Final\\ Sample}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Analysis Perform}\tabularnewline
        \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
        &  &  & \thead{No. of\\ articles} & \thead{Total local\\ citations} &  &  \thead{text} & \thead{text} \tabularnewline
        \midrule
        (("determinants" or "discrimination") and ("finance" or "credit" or  "capital" or "financial services") and ("access")) & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5\tabularnewline
        & &\tabularnewline
        ("financial inclusion") & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5\tabularnewline
        \bottomrule%
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much <3

Comment: @SeymaKalay: You're welcome. I just added some explanations on what I changed an why I changed it, in case you're interested.